# Digitalocean and Django droplet very slow after upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, django, digital-ocean

How best can I solve the issue of the server being very slow, I upgraded my droplet from :

```
Basic - Premium AMD
Shared CPU
1 vCPU
1 GB
25 GB
1 TB
```

to this :

```
Basic - Premium AMD
Shared CPU
2 vCPUs
4 GB
50 GB
4 TB
```

My endpoints are all cached, but the issue is still there.

But the site is still very slow, what other things I should consider for the better performance ?